# How to set different woocommerce Shipping Zones for the same country and show both of them

Tags: woocommerce, methods

I found that woocommerce will only show the shipping method for the shipping zone that is sorted on the top of the list(narrowest), and this default setting makes the shipping zone function become very limited.

I have 2 carriers for customers the choose,UPS and EMS.
UPS and EMS have different price rules and different shipping zone settings.

to shows both shipping methods I

and I need to create 3 types of the zone:

1. counties for UPS only
2. counties EMS only
3. Overlap countries with both UPS & EMS as methods.

that means I will need to create at least 30+ shipping zones.
mostly like create one country as one shipping zone, and that means shipping zone is useless.

I also found that someone has the same problem as me:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/intersecting-shipping-zones-not-displayed-on-checkout/

if woocommerce can display both shipping methods on different shipping zone that will be great. is it any code I can add to make it works?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with the setting of EMS and DHL, and couldn't find any reasonable solution. Therefore, I had to spend the whole day to code it manually.

Here I post it for anyone who may need this. It save shipping IDs to the datastore and use them to calculate and merge optional rates.

```
// Make and merge optional rates
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', function ( $rates, $package ){

$country           = strtoupper( wc_clean( $package['destination']['country'] ) );
$state             = strtoupper( wc_clean( $package['destination']['state'] ) );
$postcode          = wc_normalize_postcode( wc_clean( $package['destination']['postcode'] ) );
$cache_key         = WC_Cache_Helper::get_cache_prefix( 'shipping_zones' ) . 'wc_shipping_zones_' . md5( sprintf( '%s+%s+%s', $country, $state, $postcode ) );
$matching_zone_ids = wp_cache_get( $cache_key, 'shipping_zones_array' ); // get ids from the datastore cache
if ( false === $matching_zone_ids ) {
    $data_store = WC_Data_Store::load( 'shipping-zone' );
    $data_store->get_zone_id_from_package( $package );
    $matching_zone_ids = wp_cache_get( $cache_key, 'shipping_zones_array' );
}
if ( $matching_zone_ids ) : foreach ( $matching_zone_ids as $matching_zone_id ):
    $new_zone = new WC_Shipping_Zone( $matching_zone_id );
    foreach ( $new_zone->get_shipping_methods( true ) as $new_method ){
        $rates = $rates + $new_method->get_rates_for_package( $package ); // make and merge the optional rate
    }
endforeach; endif;

return  $rates;

}, 10, 2 );


add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_zone_criteria', function ( $criteria, $package, $postcode_locations ) { // set ids as array to the datastore cache 

global $wpdb;
$matching_zone_ids = array();
$matching_zones = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT zones.zone_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zones as zones LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations as locations ON zones.zone_id = locations.zone_id AND location_type != 'postcode' WHERE " . implode( ' ', $criteria ) . ' ORDER BY zone_order ASC, zones.zone_id ASC LIMIT 10' );
if ( $matching_zones ){
    foreach ( $matching_zones as $zone ){
        $matching_zone_ids[] = $zone->zone_id;
    }
}
$country           = strtoupper( wc_clean( $package['destination']['country'] ) );
$state             = strtoupper( wc_clean( $package['destination']['state'] ) );
$postcode          = wc_normalize_postcode( wc_clean( $package['destination']['postcode'] ) );
$cache_key         = WC_Cache_Helper::get_cache_prefix( 'shipping_zones' ) . 'wc_shipping_zones_' . md5( sprintf( '%s+%s+%s', $country, $state, $postcode ) );
wp_cache_set( $cache_key, $matching_zone_ids, 'shipping_zones_array' );

return $criteria;

}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: As of 7/2022 this code displays shipping options from multiple intersecting shipping zones!

Comment: You sir is a life saver. I had this problem and couldn't find a solution. I have special price list for UPS and Fedex. And they have different regions for same country. For example, in UPS, Germany is in region 1 but for fedex, it is region 2. There are a lot of price differences so your snippet saved me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Mizuho Ogino, Thank you for your code, this code solved my problem, but I have one more question: is it possible to make this code works only for specific shipping zone(s) or exclude some shipping zone(s) or country? I found that this code is incompatible with a woocommerce plugin conditional shipping and payments, it will make the restricted shipping method not getting hidden. Many thanks!

Comment: Hi @s011420. I haven't used Conditional Shipping and Payments plugin, so I can't figure out what cause an incompatibility issues. But if you want to filter specific zones, I guess you should insert the filter after getting postcode, around line 4.
`if ( !apply_filters( 'merge_woocommerce_package_rates', true, $country, $state, $postcode ) { return $rates; }`
And filter like it.
`add_filter( 'merge_woocommerce_package_rates', function ( $return, $country, $state, $postcode ){ 
 if ( $country == 'US' && $state == 'CA') { 
  $return = false;
 }
 return $return;
}, 10, 4 );`

Comment: Hi @MizuhoOgino, Thank you for your reply. I tried to add ```if ( !apply_filters( 'merge_woocommerce_package_rates', true, $country, $state, $postcode ) { return $rates; }``` after ```if ( !apply_filters( 'merge_woocommerce_package_rates', true, $country, $state, $postcode ) { return $rates; }```,but it seems this code will cause error. where should add the following code? ```add_filter( 'merge_woocommerce_package_rates', function ( $return, $country, $state, $postcode ){ if ( $country == 'US' &amp;&amp; $state == 'CA') { $return = false; } return $return; }, 10, 4 );```  Many thanks!

Comment: @s011420
 Sorry, the apply_filters is missing `)`. The code should be `$postcode ) ) { return $rates; }`. You can customize the add_filter merge_woocommerce_package_rates  and just add it after the above all filters.